# ComplexHeat: column_order is ignored when column_split is used

Tags: r, sorting, heatmap, complexheatmap

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/1166) in the ComplexHeatmap github, but I got no response so far, and was hoping someone here could lend a hand...

I am trying to make the simplest heatmap possible, but the behavior is not what I expect. I just want to produce a heatmap with no column clustering, and the samples in a specific group order (**non-alphabetical**), with groups separated by a gap.

The problem is, when I want to add such gap, the order is ignored, and defaults to an **alphabetical** order.

Check the following MWE with the `iris` data.

1- Create my data matrix (small subset of `iris` for just `setosa` and `virginica` Species), and a meta information data frame with just sample ID and Species (my grouping variable):

```
data(iris)
my_setosa=subset(iris, Species=="setosa")
my_virginica=subset(iris, Species=="virginica")
set.seed(123)
rows_used1 <- sort(sample(1:nrow(my_setosa), 5, replace = F))
rows_used2 <- sort(sample(1:nrow(my_virginica), 5, replace = F))
my_iris=rbind(my_setosa[rows_used1,], my_virginica[rows_used2,])
#
heat_mat=t(as.matrix(my_iris[,-ncol(my_iris)]))
meta_df=data.frame(ID=paste0("id",rownames(my_iris)), Species=my_iris[,ncol(my_iris)])
meta_df$Species=droplevels(meta_df$Species)
colnames(heat_mat)=meta_df$ID
```

These look like this:

```
> heat_mat
             id3 id14 id15 id31 id42 id114 id125 id137 id143 id150
Sepal.Length 4.7  4.3  5.8  4.8  4.5   5.7   6.7   6.3   5.8   5.9
Sepal.Width  3.2  3.0  4.0  3.1  2.3   2.5   3.3   3.4   2.7   3.0
Petal.Length 1.3  1.1  1.2  1.6  1.3   5.0   5.7   5.6   5.1   5.1
Petal.Width  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.3   2.0   2.1   2.4   1.9   1.8
> meta_df
      ID   Species
1    id3    setosa
2   id14    setosa
3   id15    setosa
4   id31    setosa
5   id42    setosa
6  id114 virginica
7  id125 virginica
8  id137 virginica
9  id143 virginica
10 id150 virginica
```

2- Define heatmap and Species grouping colors, column annotation (Species groups), column order and column split (gap between Species groups):

```
palette=grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(11)
col_vec=c("red","blue")
col_vec=stats::setNames(col_vec, levels(meta_df$Species))
column_ha <- ComplexHeatmap::HeatmapAnnotation(
               Species = meta_df$Species,
               col = list(Species = col_vec),
               show_legend = TRUE)
column_order=meta_df[order(meta_df$Species, decreasing=T),]$ID
column_split <- meta_df$Species
```

Note here (and this is the problem), that I want the `virginica` group on the left, and the `setosa` group on the right, so my column order is the following:

```
> column_order
 [1] "id114" "id125" "id137" "id143" "id150" "id3"   "id14"  "id15"  "id31"
[10] "id42"
```

3- Make the heatmap without `column_split`:

```
complex_heat <- ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(heat_mat, cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE,
                                        row_dend_width = grid::unit(2, "inch"),
                                        rect_gp = grid::gpar(col = "white", lwd = 2),
                                        col = palette,
                                        top_annotation = column_ha,
                                        column_order = column_order,
                                        #column_split = column_split,
                                        column_gap = grid::unit(0.1, "inch"),
                                        border = TRUE)
grDevices::png(filename="heatmap.png", height=400, width=600)
ComplexHeatmap::draw(complex_heat)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

This is all good, the heatmap produced below has my sample IDs ordered correctly with `virginica` on the left (in blue as specified by `col_vector`), and `setosa` on the right (in red as specified by `col_vector`):

[image: test1]

4- Make the heatmap **with** `column_split`; if I just uncomment the `column_split` line that specifies to split the column by the Species variable, I woould expect the exact same heatmap, with just a gap between the two Species groups. However, the `column_order` is ignored, and `setosa` samples appear on the left...

```
complex_heat <- ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(heat_mat, cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE,
                                        row_dend_width = grid::unit(2, "inch"),
                                        rect_gp = grid::gpar(col = "white", lwd = 2),
                                        col = palette,
                                        top_annotation = column_ha,
                                        column_order = column_order,
                                        column_split = column_split,
                                        column_gap = grid::unit(0.1, "inch"),
                                        border = TRUE)
```

[image: test2]

... you could argue that `column_split` needs to be a character vector instead of a factor, or that it needs to be in the same order as the samples in `column_order` (which should not be the case, it should map to the `heat_mat` and `meta_df` order).

Obviously enough, if you just do `column_split=rev(column_split)` and try to produce the heatmap again, the sample grouping gets messed up:

[image: test3]

I am at a loss... this should be extremely easy to accomplish, but I cannot work it out, and in my real world case it's not just a cosmetic option.

Anybody has a clue, or is this just a bug of the package and this cannot be accomplished? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using factor instead of character (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933195/not-getting-correct-row-order-in-the-row-split-complexheatmap-r/78101428#78101428)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone needs this, `column_split` should be a **factor** with the same order as `meta_df$Species`, but the levels specified in the order we want them plotted...

`column_split=rev(column_split))` or `levels(column_split)=rev(levels(column_split))` (what I was trying) do not work cause they mess up the sample group assignments as the order with respect to `meta_df$Species` changes.

The solution is to define `column_split` like this:

`column_split=factor(as.character(meta_df$Species), levels=c('virginica','setosa'))`

... instead of `column_split <- meta_df$Species`

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience. I met a similar issue when I tried to apply the row cluster on a new matrix to reproduce the row cluster -- the row order was messed up. May I have your suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78184614/r-complexheatmap-cannot-reproduce-exact-row-orders-when-apply-row-clusters-to-ne Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I just saw this! let me post an answer for your question.